# Addition or Subtraction of a number from each element of a list using Tcl Script

Tags: tcl

I have a input file name "input.dat" with the values as:

```
7 0
9 9
0 2
2 1
3 4
4 6
5 7
5 6
```

And I want to add/subtract any number from column 2 by converting it into a list using Tcl Script. I have written the Tcl Script as follows:

```
set input [open "input.dat" r]
set data [read $input]
set values [list]
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    if {$line eq ""} {break}
    lappend values [lindex [split $line " "] 1]
}
puts "$values-2"
close $input
```

But the output comes out to be: `0 9 2 1 4 6 7 6-2`

Can anybody help me, how to fix this problem ? or what is the error in the script ? It's also helpful if anybody can help me with a correct script.

Comment: The `$values` list is the data from that column, and all you've done so far is print it as a string with a literal `-2` appended. But **what exactly do you mean by “add/subtract any number”?** I can interpret that in several ways, so you need to be exact.

Comment: @DonalFellows I want to substract 2 from from each element of the list. For example, 0-2, 9-2, 2-2 and get the values as a list again. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Off topic, but can I ask why you are creating a new account each time you have a new question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but the options all seem to be solvable with the `lmap` command, which is for applying an operation to each element of a list.

Here's how to concatenate each element with `-2`:

```
set values [lmap val $values {
    string cat $val "-2"
}]
```

Here's how to subtract 2 from each element:

```
set values [lmap val $values {
    expr {$val - 2}
}]
```

Comment: I believe it's the latter.

Comment: I've given both. Which will be fine except it's all got to be backported to some crazy-old version of Tcl…

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes, I found my mistake. Actually I had written puts "$values-2" but the correct command is puts "[expr {$values-2}]". I skipped the "expr" part; now the problem is solved. 

Thank you very much for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

puts will treat it as a string, you'll have to use [expr $val - 2]

NOTE: If it doesn't work, it is possible your input list is a string not int or float (Depends on how the values were read). In this case you can use:

scan $val %d tmp

set newval [expr $tmp - 2]

puts $newval

This will convert your string to int before applying mathematical expressions. You can similarly convert to float by using %f in scan instead of %d